# Difference between Probability and Score of a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: data-visualization, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I am referring to this paper here: https://rajpurkar.github.io/mlx/visualizing-cnns/

I am confused as to the difference between the Score and the Probability of a Neural Network. Where does the score come from, and how is it computed? Lastly, in the paper, they state that the score is used in conjunction with back propagation. In my understanding, back propagation works by calculating gradients of different layers. These gradients can be used to determine loss information. The loss information is used to change the weights in the neural network. The loss is correlated with the probability of a neural network, but the loss isn't correlated with a score. This is my confusion point, I don't understand how you can use the score with back propagation, and that has led me to question my understanding of the score itself.

Thankyou for the responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note: the score $S_c(I)$ is the score that the neural network assigns to a class before the softmax, not the probability $P_c=\frac{e^{S_c}}{\sum_ce^{S_c}}$.

So the score is just the output of the last layer of the network before the softmax activation function (which creates a normalized vector of probabilities) is applied. So the score and the probability are directly related by a nonlinear function.